# How to get access token in the new Facebook Oauth Api?

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the new facebook oauth api. The one for php 4. I am trying application where user can login with there facebook account. Since I am using laravel 4 for my project I am using this [package](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/). In this package there is a line `$session = new FacebookSession('access-token-here');` But from where will I get the access token? In the previous version of the api there was a function called `getAccessToken()`. I am really confused. Thanks in advance.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Facebook PHP SDK (v4.0.x), you need to save the `$session` after the user has logged in, e.g.:

```
$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
```

Then, when the user returns, you can load the session back in as follows:

```
$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
```

You will obviously need to do some error checking and the correct login flow for the code. You can [take a look at this tutorial for more help](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. where did you get the session variable?